# Communication between one to many component react native

Tags: react-native

I'm new in react native development.I have 3 components. initially first component was loaded.Pushing from 1 component to 2 component and again pushing from 2 component to 3 component. if 3 component i'm doing some changes same time i want to refresh back 1 & 2 component.when i click on back button not refreshed.How can i refresh it?

```
1 component ==> 2 component ==> 3 component (if login is success how can i refresh back component method)
```

Comment: You should read this https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html or use a better solution i.e. redux.

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea of React is downwards data flow.  The state should be held in a parent component and flow downwards to the child components.  When you want to change the state from a child component, you need to lift the state back up into the parent component.

One concept that is important here is the difference between component types: smart vs dumb, or presentational vs. container.  Basically, the smart/container components hold the state and logic, where dumb/presentational components just present the UI. Here is a great article:

https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Also, in React and React-Native, the components don't exactly refresh.  There is a process called diffing, where a snapshot of the previous DOM tree is taken and compared to the DOM tree with the next state props, and only the changes are rendered.  So, all you have to do is change the state in the parent/smart/container component, React will take care of the re-render through diffing.

So, something like this will do the trick:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class Parent extends Component {
    state = { isLoggedIn: false, otherState: '' }

    _handleLogin = () => {
        //do login stuff
        this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <ChildOne handleLogin={this._handleLogin} {...this.state} />
            {this.state.isLoggedIn &&
              <Text>Now logged in!</Text>
            }
          </View>
        )
    }

}

const ChildOne = props => (
    <View>
        <Grandchild {...props} />
    </View>
);

const Grandchild = props => (
    <Button 
        onPress={() => props.handleLogin()}
        title="some title"
    />
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  }
});
```

Here is a snack where you can see it on your device:
https://snack.expo.io/SkhOTvkVb

Answer (score 2):

You can pass data to one component to another by using props

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
} from 'react-native';

export default class ComponentOne extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <ComponentTwo
                text="Hello"
            />
        )
    }
}

class ComponentTwo extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <ComponentThree
                textTwo={this.props.text}
            />
        )
    }
}


class ComponentThree extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <View><Text>{this.props.textTwo}</Text></View>
        )
    }
}
```

For more details refer this link http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.45/docs/props.html#props